# What is the proper way to add files to a packaged electron app?

Tags: electron, electron-packager

How do I put a a custom file into the root folder of an electron package when building?

I'm trying to add a file to the root of my electron app when it's packaged. Below is what I currently have. It works to an extent, but then code-signing fails.

```
export const packagerOptions = {
    name: 'app',
    platform: 'win32',
    arch: 'x64',
    dir: path.join(__dirname, '../'),
    out: path.join(__dirname, '../dist/packaged'),
    ignore: [
        /^\/(build|e2e|src)($|\/)/,
        /^\/dist\/(installer|packaged)($|\/)/,
        /^\/node_modules\/edge\/(build|test)($|\/)/,
        /^\/node_modules\/edge\/.+\\.(dll|node)$/,
        /^\/node_modules\/electron-edge-js\/(?!.+8\.9\.3).+\.(dll|node)$/,
    ],
    icon: path.join(__dirname, '../assets/win32/app.ico'),
    asar: {
        unpack: '*.{dll,ico,node}'
    },
    prune: true,
    overwrite: true,
    win32metadata: {
        CompanyName: 'App Co',
        FileDescription: 'App Desktop',
        ProductName: 'App Desktop',
        InternalName: 'App Desktop'
    },
    afterExtract: [safeFFMPEG],
    afterCopy: [serialHooks([
        (buildPath, electronVersion, platform, arch, callback) => {
            fs.copyFile(
                path.join(__dirname, '../assets/extraResources/MYFILE'),
                path.join(buildPath, '..', '..', 'MYFILE'),
                err => console.log(err, 'an error occurred'));
        }
    ])],
};
```

I've tried using:

```
extraResource: [
    path.join(__dirname, '../assets/extraResources/MYFILE')
],
```

but that puts it in the resources/ folder. I need it to be in the parent folder of resources.